# Why does Run.Text bind two-way by default?

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

In .NET 4.0, [Run.Text](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.run.text%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) is bindable. So I tried to bind it:

```
<Run Text="{Binding DisplayText}"/>
```

But when I ran, I got an error: "A TwoWay or OneWayToSource binding cannot work on the read-only property 'DisplayText' of type 'SomeNamespace.SomeClass'."

My DisplayText property was indeed read-only, but so is a Run -- Runs go in in TextBlocks, which you can't edit. So why would I be getting this error? I dug into PresentationFramework with [dotPeek](http://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/) and sure enough:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("Text", typeof (string), typeof (Run),
    (PropertyMetadata) new FrameworkPropertyMetadata((object) string.Empty,
        FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault,
        new PropertyChangedCallback(Run.OnTextPropertyChanged),
        new CoerceValueCallback(Run.CoerceText)));
```

The fourth line, plain as day, specifies that Run.Text should bind two-way by default, which makes no sense and seems like a glaring design bug.

Of course, this is easy enough to work around:

```
<Run Text="{Binding DisplayText, Mode=OneWay}"/>
```

But why should I *have* to work around it? **Why does Run bind two-way by default?**

Comment: Great question. 6 years later and new developers are still running into the same issue.  I even forget about it myself until I hit the binding at runtime!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just a guess here:

It might be because `Run` objects are also used in the `RichTextBox` control, and I can imagine this control might want to Bind `TwoWay` by default!

Comment: This is incorrect. Docs say binding is not enabled in RichTextBox because it would be too easy to clear the binding with edit operations. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.run.text.aspx